# How to increment numeric part of a string by one?

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a string formed up by numbers and sometimes by letters.

Example `AF-1234` or `345ww`.

I have to get the numeric part and increment it by one.
how can I do that? maybe with regex?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use `preg_replace_callback` as:

```
function inc($matches) {
    return ++$matches[1];
}

$input = preg_replace_callback("|(\d+)|", "inc", $input);
```

Basically you match the numeric part of the string using the regex `\d+` and replace it with the value returned by the callback function which returns the incremented value.

[**Ideone link**](http://www.ideone.com/if8pN)

Alternatively this can be done using `preg_replace()` with the `e` modifier as:

```
 $input = preg_replace("|(\d+)|e", "$1+1", $input);
```

[**Ideone link**](http://www.ideone.com/WZdrv)

Comment: what if i have string like "XXX-342"? it will be in $matches[0] or $matches[1]?

Comment: @codaddict: Don't you think that callback is a "little" overhead there? Why don't use regular `+ 1`?

Comment: @tampe125: It will be in both [0] and [1]

Comment: @zerkms: You are right, this can be easily done using `preg_replace` with `e` modifier. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: According to PHP documentation `e` modifier has been removed in PHP 7, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: PHP says "ErrorException (E_ERROR)
preg_replace(): The /e modifier is no longer supported, use preg_replace_callback instead" :D

Comment: zeros on the left are not supported, for example: "K0001" => "K2".

Answer (score 10):

If the string ends with numeric characters it is this simple...

```
$str = 'AF-1234';
echo $str++; //AF-1235
```

That works the same way with '345ww' though the result may not be what you expect.

```
$str = '345ww';
echo $str++; //345wx
```

@tampe125

This example is probably the best method for your needs if incrementing string that end with numbers.

```
$str = 'XXX-342';
echo $str++; //XXX-343
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is an example that worked for me by doing a pre increment on the value

```
$admNo = HF0001;
$newAdmNo = ++$admNo;
```

The above code will output `HF0002`

Answer (score 2):

If you are dealing with strings that have multiple number parts then it's not so easy to solve with regex, since you might have numbers overflowing  from one numeric part to another.

For example if you have a number `INV00-10-99` which should increment to `INV00-11-00`.

I ended up with the following:

```
for ($i = strlen($string) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
  if (is_numeric($string[$i])) {
    $most_significant_number = $i;
    if ($string[$i] < 9) {
      $string[$i] = $string[$i] + 1;
      break;
    }
    // The number was a 9, set it to zero and continue.
    $string[$i] = 0;
  }
}

// If the most significant number was set to a zero it has overflowed so we
// need to prefix it with a '1'.
if ($string[$most_significant_number] === '0') {
  $string = substr_replace($string, '1', $most_significant_number, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to the answer above, but contains the code inline and does a full check for the last character.

```
function replace_title($title) {
    $pattern = '/(\d+)(?!.*\d)+/';
    return preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($m) { return ++$m[0]; }, $title);
}

echo replace_title('test 123'); // test 124
echo replace_title('test 12 3'); // test 12 4
echo replace_title('test 123 - 2'); // test 123 - 3
echo replace_title('test 123 - 3 - 5'); // test 123 - 3 - 6
echo replace_title('123test'); // 124test
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some Python code that does what you ask. Not too great on my PHP, but I'll see if I can convert it for you.

```
>>> import re
>>> match = re.match(r'(\D*)(\d+)(\D*)', 'AF-1234')
>>> match.group(1) + str(int(match.group(2))+1) + match.group(3)
'AF-1235'
```

Comment: Others have already answered in PHP. I'll leave this here in case someone finds it useful though.