# Rails / Ruby method / regex to increment numeric part of string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby

Related to an old PHP question here:

[How to increment numeric part of a string by one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313288/how-to-increment-numeric-part-of-a-string-by-one)

I can have any random format of strings (invoice numbers) like this:

- INV-005
- INV-5
- 5567
- 5567-1A
- 5567-001A
- INVOICE
- etc.

I would like to take these as an input and output:

- INV-006
- INV-6
- 5568
- 5567-2A
- 5567-002A
- INVOICE-1
- etc.

The last numeric portion is incremented by one.  In the case where there is no match it returns "" OR just adds a "-1" to the end.  I can handle the logic on my end if its easier to just return "".

On the ruby / rails side it would seem to be like this:

```
"foo".gsub(/(o+)/, '\1\1\1')
#=> "foooooo"
```

I just can't seem to figure out the regex logic.

Comment: You probably mean `(\d*)\z` to capture the trailing digits, if any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the method [String#succ](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-succ).

```
def increment_numeric(str)
  str.gsub(/\d+/) { |s| s.succ }
end
```

```
increment_numeric "INV-005"  #=> "INV-006"
increment_numeric "INV-5"    #=> "INV-6"
increment_numeric "5567"     #=> "5568"
increment_numeric "5567-1A"  #=> "5568-2A"
increment_numeric "567-001A" #=> "568-002A"
increment_numeric "INVOICE"  #=> "INVOICE"
```

---

In view of the asker's comment below, the following might be more appropriate.

```
R = /\d+\z|(?<=\d)\p{L}\z/
```

```
def increment_numeric(str)
  str.sub(R) { |s| s.succ }
end
```

```
increment_numeric "INV-005"   #=> "INV-006"
increment_numeric "INV-5"     #=> "INV-6"
increment_numeric "5567"      #=> "5568"
increment_numeric "5567-01"   #=> "5567-02"
increment_numeric "5567-1A"   #=> "5567-1B"
increment_numeric "567-001A"  #=> "567-001B"
increment_numeric "A567-001B" #=> "A567-001C"
increment_numeric "INVOICE-1" #=> "INVOICE-2"
increment_numeric "INVOICE"   #=> "INVOICE"
```

The regular expression reads can be written in *free spacing mode* to make it self-documenting:

```
R =
/
\d+\z    # match one or more digits at the end of the string
|        # or
(?<=\d)  # assert that the following match is preceded by a digit
\p{L}\z  # match one Unicode letter at the end of the string
/x       # invoke free-spacing regex definition mode
```

`(?<=\d)` is a *positive lookbehind*.

There is at most one substitution so either `gsub` or `sub` can be used.

Comment: That is perfect - I may even just call `.succ` direct and ignore the regex.  For example "5567-1A".succ => "5567-1B" which acctually makes more sence.  I am really just trying to guess at the next increment.  The user needs to confirm.

Comment: Dan, I modified my answer in view of your comment. You may wish to remove your first comment as it is no longer relevant.